# Python mathematical sequence

Tags: python, recursion, math, sequence

I have to write code to manually input n number and code should find that n member of sequence.n should be natural number. Formula for that sequence is

```
f(n)=(f(n-1))²-1
```

First member is 2 second 3 third 8 and every next is one less than square of number before. The code should print that n member of sequence which is inputted.
For example

```
In:3
Out:8

In:4
Out:63
```

I wrote code but it don't work

```
n = int(input("'input n:"))

def f(n):
  if n < 0:
    print('Undefined')
  else:
    return (f(n - 1) ** 2) - 1

print(f(n))
```

Comment: You need to define what the base case is, and return something in that case.

Comment: *"it didn't work"* is not particularly helpful.  Does it raise an error, give the wrong result, get stuck in an infinite loop, etc.?  Please describe the problem *in detail*.

Comment: It obviously gets an error when it tries to raise `None` to a power.

Comment: what should the function return when n=0 ?

Comment: The value of your base case is 2; `2**2 - 1 == 3`, `3**2 -1 == 8`, etc. Based on your unnecessary error output, you seem to have decided on `f(0) == 2`. For negative values, you should probably  just raise a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 1):

In recursion, you need to return a definite value for the stop index.

Here you just have to write in your code that the first value of the sequence is 2:

```
def f(n):
  if n < 0:
    raise ValueError('Undefined')  # better to raise to make sure to abort
  elif n == 0:
    return 2  
  else:
    return (f(n - 1) ** 2) - 1
```

That is enough for `f(1)` to return 3 and `f(2)` to return 8...